# Subfigures with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats, groupplots

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx, float}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\def\figone{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
             width = 1.2\textwidth,
             height = \textwidth,
             grid = both,
             xtick distance = 1,
             ymin = 0,
             ymax = 2,
             ytick distance = 0.4,
             xlabel = $t/\tau$,
             ylabel = $V/V_0$
            ]
            \addplot[red, ultra thick]{exp(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\def\figtwo{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
             width = 1.2\textwidth,
             height = \textwidth,
             grid = both,
             xtick distance = 1,
             ymin = 0,
             ymax = 2,
             ytick distance = 0.4,
             yticklabels={,,},
             xlabel = $t/\tau$
            ]
            \addplot[blue, ultra thick]{exp(2*x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \figone
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{5.5mm}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \figtwo
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}





\end{document}
```

[image]

Observe that I used `\hspace{5.5mm}` to gather the graphs. I got such value of 5.5mm by trial and error. If I comment that line, the graphs will merge such that the value 0 of the left plot will coincide with the edge of the right one.

**My question is:**
Is there any way to make the plots automatically glue together side by side?

Comment: The MWE does not compile.

Comment: Strange... it compiles for me. I will try changing `documentclass` to `article`... if it works, I will edit the post.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: I added a picture to show the result.

Comment: Strange indeed (I get `dimension too large` errors...). Anyway, I think you will find what your are looking for in `pgfplots` manual, section 4.19 (Alignment Options), p.369.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is to use PGFPlots [groupplots](/questions/tagged/groupplots) library when you don't need to separate images.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=2 by 1,
            horizontal sep=0pt,
            % show `ylabel` and `yticklabels` only on the left (most) plot
            y descriptions at=edge left,
        },
        width=0.45\textwidth,
        height=0.45\textwidth,
        grid=both,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=0.4,
        xlabel=$t/\tau$,
        ylabel=$V/V_0$,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot [red,ultra thick] {exp(x)};
    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot [blue,ultra thick] {exp(0.5*x)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]